# Getting a Bad Request when im Posting Data with requests

Tags: python, post, python-requests, steam, bad-request

Im always getting the error message "Bad Request" when im trying to Post data to steam, i did lot of resears and i dont know how to fix this.

Post Values:

```
# Post Values    
total = int(item['price'])
fee = int(item['fee'])
subtotal = total-fee
```

Cookies:

```
# Cookies
c = []
c.append('steamMachineAuthXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX='+steamMachineAuth)
c.append('steamLogin='+steamLogin)
c.append('steamLoginSecure='+steamLoginSecure)
c.append('sessionid='+sessionid)
cookie = ''
for value in c:
    cookie = cookie+''+value+'; '
```

Headers:

```
# Headers
headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Host": "steamcommunity.com",
    "Referer": hosturl+"market/listings/"+appid+"/"+item['market_hash_name'],
    "Cookie": cookie,
    "Origin": hosturl,
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
```

Post data:

```
# Post Data
post = {
    'sessionid': sessionid,
    'currency': int(currency),
    'subtotal': subtotal,
    'fee': fee,
    'total': total,
    'quantity': 1
}
```

Url:

```
# url
url = hosturl+'market/buylisting/'+item['listingid']
```

Sending Request:

```
# Sending Request
se = requests.Session()
re = se.post(url, data=post, headers=headers)
print re.reason
```

Output: 
    Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak specifically about the Steam service as I haven't used it yet, but my experience with typical *Bad Request* responses is that you're either trying an HTTP verb that isn't supported or your request is not formatted correctly.

In your case, I suspect it's the latter.

My first candidate to look at is your cookie formatting. Are you sure you don't have characters that need to be escaped?

I could suggest using something like this instead:

```
c = { 
    'steamMachineAuthXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX': steamMachineAuth,
    'steamLogin': steamLogin,
    'steamLoginSecure': steamLoginSecure,
    'sessionid': sessionid
}
cookie = '; ',join('{}="{}"'.format(k, v) for k, v in c.items())
```

Comment: I tried many possible ways to send cookies, headers and post data, so i think there is a different problem. Maybe some data is Missing.